# Difference between Laplace estimate and Expected likelihood estimate?

Tags: python, statistics, probability, sentiment-analysis

I'm doing a research in sentiment analysis using Python and at the moment I'm having some confusion with nltk.probability

What is the difference between Laplace estimate and Expected likelihood estimate?
What is the appropriate smoothing technique from those two for sentiment analysis research?

Here's the definition from [NLTK documentation](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/probability.html) -

> **The Laplace estimate** for the probability distribution of the
>   experiment used to generate a frequency distribution.  The "Laplace
>   estimate" approximates the probability of a sample with count *c* from
>   an experiment with *N* outcomes and *B* bins as
>   *(c+1)/(N+B)*.  This is equivalent to adding one to the count for each bin, and taking the maximum likelihood estimate of the resulting
>   frequency distribution.
>
> **The expected likelihood estimate** for the probability distribution of
>   the experiment used to generate a frequency distribution.  The
>   "expected likelihood estimate" approximates the probability of a
>   sample with count *c* from an experiment with *N* outcomes and
>   *B* bins as *(c+0.5)/(N+B/2)*.  This is equivalent to adding 0.5 to the count for each bin, and taking the maximum likelihood estimate of
>   the resulting frequency distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is a large number of possible events that have not been seen, Laplace technique assigns nearly all probability mass to the data not seen before. ELE compensates for this by making alpha smaller - 0.5, thus assigning less data to unseen events.

Take a look at [here](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/james/CSC248/Lec3.pdf) for more details